# how to append a method to a angularjs controller from a different js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, content-management-system

I have an angularjs site and I want to make a CMS layer that will be combined with my normal site. I only want it's business-logic to be loaded if I am an admin and go to a specific link.

For example, if I enter as an admin, on every item a "X" button will appear so I can delete it from the DB.
If I enter as a regular user I won't be able to even know there is another layer, even if I check the resources.

**What is the best way to append a controller or module retroactively?**

One idea I thought about is attaching a controller to the view that will actually be empty, but if I enter a specific link - a different js file will be loaded which will contain the actual code for the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, hiding the security layer code from user. I used directives and I changed the templateUrl based on the current user group. I created a method to get the appropriate templateUrl.

Comment: thanks for your attention. in your project, was  that additional layer included initially in the code or was it appended retroactively according to the situation?

Comment: Appended later based on the need.